# GitHub - Failed to locate other GitHub public accounts to add as collaborator

Tags: github

I am new to GitHub and ran into a strange problem.  I have a GitHub Enterprise account, and am trying to add other GitHub account users as collaborators to a repo.  When I searched for their user names, it errored with a message "XXX isn't a GitHub member".   I am very sure that the users I am trying to add just created free public accounts on Github.com and I am searching with the right user names.  Can anyone shine some light?

Thanks,

Annie

Answer (score 2):

GitHub.com and your GitHub enterprise are two completely different different instances. They do not share any user data.

This means to add a collaborator to a project on your GitHub enterprise instance the user needs to create an account on *this* GitHub enterprise instance and not on GitHub.com